# If $\{X_{t}:t\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is strictly stationary, then $Y_{t}:=g(X_{t},\dots, X_{t+m-1})$ is also strictly stationary.

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

A stochastic process $\{X_{t}:t\in \mathbb{T}\}$ is strictly stationary if its finite dimensional distribution is stable under any time shift: for any $r\in\mathbb{T}$, any $t_{1},\dots, t_{n}\in\mathbb{T}$ with any $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$, we have $$(X_{t_{1}+r},\dots, X_{t_{n}+r})=_{d}(X_{t_{1}},\dots, X_{t_{n}}).$$ In other words,
for any Borel sets $B_{1},\dots, B_{n}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we have $$\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}+r}\in B_{1},\dots, X_{t_{n}+r}\in  B_{n})=\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}}\in B_{1},\dots,X_{t_{n}}\in B_{n}).$$

Let us assume that $\mathbb{T}:=\mathbb{Z}$.  Fix $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ and let $g:\mathbb{R}^{m}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Borel function. Define $Y_{t}:=g(X_{t},X_{t+1},\dots, X_{t+m-1})$. I want to show that

> The stochastic process $\{Y_{t}:t\in\mathbb{T}\}$ is also strictly stationary.

---

I can show it for $m=1$, but I don't know how to do it for $m\geq 1$ because of the following issue:

Fixing $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$, let $t_{1},\dots, t_{n},r\in \mathbb{T}$. Let $B_{1},\dots, B_{n}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then since $g$ is Borel measurable, $g^{-1}(B_{1}),\dots, g^{-1}(B_{n})\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{m})$. So, we can write

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}&(Y_{t_{1}}\in B_{1},\dots, Y_{t_{n}}\in B_{n})\\
&=\mathbb{P}((X_{t_{1}},\dots, X_{t_{1}+m-1})\in g^{-1}(B_{1}),\dots, (X_{t_{n}},\dots, X_{t_{n}+m-1})\in g^{-1}(B_{n})).
\end{align*}
The thing now is that I don't know how to further write it in the form of
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{1}}\in A_{1,1},\dots X_{t_{n}+m-1}\in A_{n,m})\ \text{for some Borel sets}\ A_{1,1},\dots, A_{n,m}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$$ Only from here I can use the definition of the strict stationarity.

---

I've thought of using projection map, but we won't have $\pi^{-1}(g^{-1}(B_{1})$, but $\pi(g^{-1}(B_{1})$ instead, which is not necessarily a Borel set. I am happy to use other definitions of "$=_{d}$", such as

For any Borel set $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, we have $$\mathbb{P}((X_{t_{1}+r},\dots, X_{t_{n}+r})\in B)=\mathbb{P}((X_{t_{1}},\dots, X_{t_{n}})\in B).$$ But I don't think that this will help me either.

I think that we can simplify the matter to $m=2$, then the result follows by an induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition
$$
\forall n,\forall B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}),\forall r\in\mathbb Z,\quad 
\mathbb{P}((X_{1+r},\dots, X_{n+r})\in B)=\mathbb{P}((X_{1},\dots, X_{n})\in B)
$$
is more convenient.

In order to check stationarity of $(Y_t)$, take a Borel set $C$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and $r\in\mathbb Z$.
Then
$$
\left\{ \left(Y_{1+r},\dots,Y_{n+r}\right)\in C\right\}
=\left\{\left( X_{1+r},\dots,X_{n+r+m}\right)\in B\right\},
$$
where
$$
B=\left\{\left(u_1,\dots,u_{m+n}\right)\in\mathbb R^{m+n}, 
\left(g\left(u_1,\dots,u_{m+1}\right),\dots,g\left(u_{n+1},\dots,u_{n+m}\right)\right)\in C\right\}.
$$
Then we conclude by stationarity of $(X_t)$:
$$
\mathbb P\left(\left(Y_{1+r},\dots,Y_{n+r}\right)\in C\right)=
\mathbb P\left(\left( X_{1+r},\dots,X_{n+r+m}\right)\in B\right)=\mathbb P\left(\left( X_{1},\dots,X_{n+m}\right)\in B\right)\\
=\mathbb P\left(\left(Y_{1},\dots,Y_{n}\right)\in C\right).
$$

Comment: Yeah. I agree on the first equality, but how do you prove that $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n+m})$?

Comment: The map $(u_1,\dots,u_{m+n})\mapsto \left(g\left(u_1,\dots,u_{m+1}\right),\dots,g\left(u_{n+1},\dots,u_{n+m}\right)\right)$ is measurable, because all the coordinate maps are measurable (that is, $(u_1,\dots,u_{m+n})\mapsto g(u_1, \ldots,u_{m+1})$ is measurable, as well as $(u_1,\dots,u_{m+n})\mapsto g(u_2, \ldots,u_{m+2})$ and so on.

Comment: Nice proof I forgot the coordinate measurable thing. Thx!